# Laravel 5.7: Is API request or not?

Tags: api, laravel-5

Hi I am working on a project, and I want to use the same Controller for both API and WEB, is there a function that can tell whether it is a API request or Web ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother everyone, after a long research I think i found a solution

```
if( $request->is('api/*')){
    //write your logic for api call
}else{
    //write your logic for web call
}
```